# How to layout a form

Tags: html, layout

Let's say I want to layout my page like this:

```
Label: <inputField>        Label: <inputField>
Label: <inputField>        Label: <inputField>

<-------------------- LINE ------------------>

Label: <inputField>
Label: <inputField>
Label: <inputField>
Label: <inputField> <inputField>

<-------------------- LINE ------------------>

<button> <button> <button> <checkbox>
```

I would do it using `<table>` for layouting the form objects and `<hr>` for the lines.

But I'm not sure if this is a "nice" solution. (I don't like all the tables beeing generated...)

Shoud I better use `<div>` elements for this layout?
Or how would you do it?

Comment: This is not related to JSF. All JSF does is generating a bunch of HTML. Whatever HTML targeted answer (or duplicate question link) you get, it should easily be backported to JSF since it just allows inlining plain HTML around the components. I removed the JSF tag.

Comment: `<hr>` for line is fine, because `hr` *is* a line. Fields, on the other hand, are not really *table rows*. Therefore, use CSS `float` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a form, you can style the `labels` and the `inputs`.  You should do it that way.

**EDIT**

The quick and dirty version.  Adjust as necessary.

```
<div class="labelLeft"><label>left label</label> <input /></div> 
<div class="labelRight"><label>right label</label> <input /></div> 

<br />

<div class="labelLeft"><label>left label</label> <input /></div> 
<div class="labelRight"><label>right label</label> <input /></div>

<br />

<div class="labelLeft"><label>left label</label> <input /></div> 
<div class="labelRight"><label>right label</label> <input /></div> 

<hr />

<label>label</label> <input /><br /><br />
<label>label</label> <input /><br /><br />
<label>label</label> <input /><br /><br />
<label>label</label> <input /> <input />

<hr />

<button></button> <button></button> <button></button> &nbsp;<input type="checkbox" /> 

div.labelLeft{float:left; width:250px;}
div.labelright{float:right; width:250px;}
label{border:1px solid red;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/XzhDd/

Answer (score 0):

you can get away without `<h:panelGrid>` 
add styleClass for each input
and handle the css for these labels

You probably just need these two attributes : `display :  inline` and `float : left / right`

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look a [blueprintCSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) for an example how they do their [form layouts](http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/forms.html).
Basically they've a 960-grid-system which you can also use to layout your forms.

[960.gs](http://960.gs/) is also worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gcummins/HHMu7/ . You can float the labels/inputs that are on the left, and provide a left-margin for the label on the right to force them beyond the left inputs.

Markup:

```
<form id="sebi_form">
    <label for="input1"class="left_column">Input 1</label>
    <input name="input1" id="input1" type="text" class="left_column" />
    <label for="input2"class="right_column">Input 2</label>
    <input name="input2" id="input2" type="text" class="right_column" /><br class="clearfix" />
    <label for="input3" class="left_column">Input 3</label>
    <input name="input3" id="input3" type="text" class="left_column" />
    <label for="input4"class="right_column">Input 4</label>
    <input name="input4" id="input4" type="text" class="right_column" />
</form>
<hr />
<!-- More elements as needed -->
```

CSS:

```
.left_column {
    float: left;
}
label.right_column {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```